# What's a good icon to represent testing?

Tags: buttons, icons, css, graphics

Looking for an icon that could represent "click here for significance testing"  I have seen scales, bell curves, etc.  Looking for other ideas and/or graphic sources.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether your audience is well versed in statistics.

I don't know of any ready made icons for this purpose, however if your audience is aware of the concept of hypothesis testing the icon could involve the text 'H0/HA'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're versed in statistics, the text "P<" might be acceptable. I'm not a fan of using text for icons, but it's short enough that it's workable, and it's less ambiguous than say, a bell, which could mean plenty of things.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people use icons that look like test tubes or conical flasks, and generally anything that looks like it belongs in a laboratory should work as well. If you search test and icon on Google Image search you should be able to get some ideas of what other people have been looking at as well.

Answer (score 0):

Microscope,
Circle with a check mark inside,
Beaker,
Bar or line graph,
A simple grid with some squares filled in,
A simple pattern of check marks and x's